# Warping deformation for arbitrary cross-section under torsion

Tags: beam, cross-section

Title says it. I wish to learn the approach for programming (with FE, or with alternative discretized models) the warping deformation for each point in an arbitrary cross-section, knowing the contour of the cross-section and the external forces that are applied. Do you know of any book showing this topic? (preferably a book written from a programmer or engineer perspective).

I have found several books describing torsion, both for free-warping and constrained warping torsion, but not a practical description for finding the warping deformation at each point in the cross-section.

Comment: What is a "practical description"? Textbooks by people like Timoshenko should suffice.

Comment: A "practical description" could be for example the FEM books by Hinton and Owen, with algorithms and even code, as opposed to Zienkiewicz (who, despite working in the same team as Hinton and Owen at Swansea, wrote books which were more theoretical). Regarding your suggestion on textbooks, they don't solve problems with discretization nor FEM. And if you think that the FEM implementation is done if you have the exact differential expressions, you never wrote any FEM code. Apart from that, textbooks are usually not interested in providing the warp deformation at each point in a section.